# Como unificar pelo Python várias linhas repetidas de um arquivo em Excel?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho essa planilha no Excel, que é gerado no sistema pelo dataframe pandas

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu até consigo gerar o arquivo, o problema é que ele gera dessa forma acima. Eu preciso que, por exemplo, na coluna `nome` e `sobrenome`, ele unifique os mesmos nomes em uma única linha e, por consequência, os dados ficarão na mesma linha.

O resultado final tem que ser assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu código gera a planilha, mas não está unificando as linhas. Como posso fazer isso?

Essa é a parte do código que não consigo avançar:

```
import pandas as pd

resultado = []
mydict = {}
for row in dados:
       if mydict  != {}:
            resultado.append(mydict)
       mydict = {}
       mydict['nome'] = row['nome']
       mydict['sobrenome'] = row['sobrenome']
```

Se eu tiro esse `if` do loop `for` e coloco somente um nome específico, eu consigo que imprima tudo em uma linha, mas se volta para o `for`, ele imprime todos os `nome`s e `sobrenome`s, só que com as informações em linhas separadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você cria um `dataframe` somente com os dados que se repetem, ou seja, `nome` e `sobrenome` (que serão usados como `chave primária`), e remova as duplicadas, assim:

```py
df = dados[['nome','sobrenome']].drop_duplicates()
display(df)
```

Resultado:

| nome | sobrenome |
| --- | --- |
| João | Pedro |
| Paulo | José |

Essa tabela servirá como tabela principal para juntar as outras informações.

Agora para cada coluna de idade, você precisa criar uma tabela com a `chave primária` da tabela principal e os valores de idade de cada nome, removendo as linhas que contém valores nulos com o método `.dropna(axis=0)`, assim:

```py
for i in range(2,5):  # 2,5 são os indíces das colunas com as idades
  temp = dados.iloc[:,[0,i]].dropna(axis=0)  # Recebe a coluna nome e a coluna de idade
  df = pd.merge(df, temp)
```

Na linha

> df = pd.merge(df, temp)

estamos mesclando nossa tabela principal com a tabela temporária que contém os valores da coluna de idade.

O resultado final retorna sua tabela sem os valores nulos e duplicados:

| nome | sobrenome | Idade_Agosto_2019 | Idade_Agosto_2020 | Idade_Agosto_2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| João | Pedro | 30.0 | 31.0 | 32.0 |
| Paulo | José | 21.0 | 22.0 | 23.0 |

Comment: Bom dia Felipe, funcionou. Muito obrigado. Uma dúvida, Como retiro as casas decimais no resultado da coluna idade?

Comment: Bom dia, Fabricio, adicione `.astype('Int64')` após o método `.dropna(axis=0)` na linha da variável `temp`, ficando: `temp = dados.iloc[:,[0,i]].dropna(axis=0).astype('Int64')`.

Comment: Show. Obrigado.

Comment: Felipe. Uma outra duvida.

Nesse código abaixo, roda legal se eu tiver poucas linhas. E no caso de ter muitas linhas? Como altero essa parte no loop for?

for i in range(2,5):  # 2,5 são os indíces das colunas com as idades
  temp = dados.iloc[:,[0,i]].dropna(axis=0)  # Recebe a coluna nome e a coluna de idade
  df = pd.merge(df, temp)

Comment: Fabricio, você só ira alterar o valor de `range(2,5)` caso tenha outras columas de idade ou altere a disposição das colunas, para uma tabela com mais linhas deve funcionar normalmente. Uma pergunta, porque o nome está separado do sobrenome? Pois, caso tenha um nome repetido, acredito que resultará em algum erro.

Comment: Oi Felipe, bom dia. Obrigado pela ajuda.
 
    Entendi. Vdd, os valores dentro do range estão relacionados as colunas. Então no caso de ter mais colunas de idade, eu altero o segundo valor para a qtde máxima de colunas? É isso? 
      Não tem nenhum motivo para o nome e o sobrenome estarem separados, eu coloquei assim para estudo. Só simulação mesmo com várias situações possíveis.

Comment: Exatamente Fabricio, ao adicionar outra coluna, altere o segundo elemento do `range` para o total de colunas. Sugiro a você utilizar somente uma columa para o nome para não ocorrer problemas com primeiros nomes duplicados, porém pode ser que precise fazer algumas modificações em seu código, fico à disposição para ajudá-lo, tenha um ótimo dia.

Comment: Gratidão Felipe, bom final de semana.